# What do the numbers on the mantle mean?

Tags: tire, parts, germany

I've just removed the mantle of my back tire as it has a hole (probably cut by glass). I wanted to look for a new one, but then I realized that I'm not even certain which size it is.

So I looked on the old mantle and found more numbers than I thought:

vtech EAGLE 42-622 700x42C <MDS> (Max durability System)

[image]

700 - 42 (42-622)
[image]

NL F024   17
[image]

I guess vtech EAGLE is the brand / model name, MDS is just some advertisment. But what do the numbers mean?

(Side question: Living in Germany and biking mainly / only in the city, where and for which mantle should I look?)

Comment: The value to look for is the ISO one -- 42-622.  That size scheme is independent of whether the tire is considered 700 or 29 inch or whatever, and matching that comes as close as you can to guaranteeing that the new tire will fit.  But note that the width (42) does not need to match exactly.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It looks very much as a duplicate to me. So tire is not the metal thing but the rubber thing? If so, how is the metal called?

Comment: The "metal thing" is the *rim*.

Answer (score -1):

I think I just found the answer from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Reifengr%C3%B6%C3%9Fen-beim-Fahrrad.png:

[image]

So:

- The diameter at the outer is 700mm,
- it is 42mm wide at the outer,
- 622mm is the inner diameter

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong in the answer?